# Why can't I get the gallery block from my post type to show in my wordpress api

Tags: wordpress, rest, api, gallery

In Wordpress 5.1.1 I have custom post type called 'food'. It consist of a title and and image gallery block.

In a custom Wordpress rest API end point I want to get the image urls from the gallery.

Before i send the data i loop through the post and adds the ACF to the post and the thought the same method would work.

Have tried following Wordpress functions:

```
get_post_gallery()
get_post_gallery_images()
```

Newer method for blocks as I can understand.

```
get_post_galleries()
get_post_galleries_images()
```

This is my post loop. The ACF method works.

```
function api_get_all_posts() {
    $args = array(
        'post_type' => array(
           'food',
          ),
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'order' => 'DESC',
        'post_per_page' => '5'
    );
    $the_query = new WP_Query($args);
    $posts = $the_query->posts;

    if ( empty( $posts ) ) {
        return new WP_Error(array( 'status' => 404 ) );
    } else {
      foreach ($posts as $key => $post) {
          $ID = $post->ID;
          //Set AFC
          $posts[$key]->acf = get_fields($ID);  
          //Set images
          $posts[$key]->images = get_post_galleries_images( $ID );
     }
   }   
  return rest_ensure_response($posts);
}
```

This is the JSON i send to front-end:

```
[
 {
    "ID": 44,
    "post_author": "0",
    "post_date": "2019-04-08 22:21:48",
    "post_date_gmt": "2019-04-08 22:21:48",
    "post_content": "<!-- wp:gallery {\"ids\":    [\"88\",\"87\",\"86\",91],\"columns\":4} -->\n<ul class=\"wp-block-gallery columns-4 is-cropped\"><li class=\"blocks-gallery-item\"><figure><img src=\"http://localhost/gwp/wp-content/uploads/2019/04/food-3-823x1024.jpg\" alt=\"\" data-id=\"88\" data-link=\"http://localhost/gwp/food-3/\" class=\"wp-    image-88\"/></figure></li></ul>\n<!-- /wp:gallery -->",
    "post_title": "Food test",
    "post_excerpt": "",
    "post_status": "publish",
    "comment_status": "closed",
    "ping_status": "closed",
    "post_password": "",
    "post_name": "fodd-test",
    "to_ping": "",
    "pinged": "",
    "post_modified": "2019-04-17 08:33:39",
    "post_modified_gmt": "2019-04-17 08:33:39",
    "post_content_filtered": "",
    "post_parent": 0,
    "guid": "http://localhost/gwp/?post_type=food&#038;p=44",
    "menu_order": 0,
    "post_type": "food",
    "post_mime_type": "",
    "comment_count": "0",
    "filter": "raw",
    "acf": {
        "post_template": "food"
    },
    "images": []
}
]
```

I can see the images are there by looking at 'post_content' but it can not find the gallery. It keeps giving me an empty array in 'images'?

Any suggestion? 
thanks for reading.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These functions work only with the (old) `[gallery]` shortcode used in the classic editor, so they will not return anything with the gallery *block* (i.e. `<!-- wp:gallery ... -->...<!-- /wp:gallery -->`):

- `get_post_gallery()`
- `get_post_gallery_images()`
- `get_post_galleries()`
- `get_post_galleries_images()`

And I'm not aware of equivalent functions for the gallery block; however, you can use this custom function to get similar to what the `get_post_galleries_images()` would return: (add this to the theme `functions.php` file)

```php
function get_post_block_galleries_images( $post_id ) {
    $content = get_post_field( 'post_content', $post_id );
    $srcs = [];

    $i = -1;
    foreach ( parse_blocks( $content ) as $block ) {
        if ( 'core/gallery' === $block['blockName'] ) {
            $i++;
            $srcs[ $i ] = [];

            preg_match_all( '#src=([\'"])(.+?)\1#is', $block['innerHTML'], $src, PREG_SET_ORDER );
            if ( ! empty( $src ) ) {
                foreach ( $src as $s ) {
                    $srcs[ $i ][] = $s[2];
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return $srcs;
}
```

And then in your code, just replace this:

```
$posts[$key]->images = get_post_galleries_images( $ID );
```

with:

```
$posts[$key]->images = get_post_block_galleries_images( $ID );
```

I hope this answer helps you and other people. :)